# Can an ideal dipole experience an electric force?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

It is known that electric force a charged body is given as $\vec{F} = q \vec{E}$ given that $\vec{E}$ is uniform. Now, for an ideal dipole, what would we take as the charge for calculating the force exerted on it by an external electric field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use the formula you stated to compute the force on each component of the dipole separately and then you add them up to get the net force. Note that this will be zero unless the electric field varies in space.

To give more details, consider a dipole of positive charge $q$ with separation $d\,$ lying along the $x$-axis such that the charges are at $x = 0, x = d$.

We will take the ideal limit at the end. The force on the positive charge is $qE(d)$, while that on the negative charge is $-qE(0)$.

The total force is then $$F = q(E(d) - E(0)) = qd\frac{E(d) - E(0)}{d}$$ Now, the ideal dipole limit is $d \to 0$, with $qd = p$ fixed. We are thus left with $F = p\frac{dE}{dx}\Bigl|_{x=0}$.

Comment: The ideal dipole has no components to my knowledge

Comment: It should be made up of two opposite charges separated by a given distance, those are the components I'm referring to.

Comment: In the ideal dipole/ coming out of the limit, you don't have the positive and negative charge anymore. I understand what you are saying for the finite seperate dipole though

Comment: It's the same in the ideal case. To have any dipole at all you have to take the separation to zero while keeping the product $q d$ constant, where $q$ is the charge of the positive component and $d$ is the separation.

Comment: Thanks, this helped.

Comment: Glad to be of use!

Answer (score 6):

The electric force on a dipole is $\mathbf F=(p \cdot \boldsymbol \nabla ) \mathbf E$, where $p$ is the dipole moment, $\mathbf E$ is the electric field, and $\boldsymbol \nabla$ is the gradient operator.

Note that this force goes to zero for a uniform field (as mentioned in another answer). Note also that there will be a torque to align the dipole with the field.

Comment: How do you show that this is the case?

Comment: @Buraian I’ll leave that as an exercise for the reader; however, you can see that this expression is just a generalization of the one from the other answer.

Comment: One usually writes $(\vec p \cdot \vec \nabla)\vec E$, which is a little clearer about where the scalar part of the product is.