# Can static electricity (charged balloon) attract any liquid other than water?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge, dielectric, dipole

I know that a charged balloon can attract a stream of water, because it is a dipole. I am wondering if a charged balloon can attract any other liquid other than water? Does it have to be a dipole? What liquids can it attract?

I appreciate any answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does really attracts a water stream to a charged object?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130915/what-does-really-attracts-a-water-stream-to-a-charged-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any liquid composed of polar molecules will be attracted by a charged balloon, but water is by far the safest choice. For example, acetone, ammonia, formaldehyde, and most alcohols have comparable or larger [molecular dipole moments](https://macro.lsu.edu/Howto/solvents/dipole%20moment.htm) than water, but all are flammable or otherwise risky. (Static electricity and flammable liquids are not a safe combination.)

A charged balloon attracts polar molecules is because the electric field is non-uniform and the force on a dipole is [proportional to the gradient of the electric field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/661208/145491).  In principle, [a molecule with a quadrupole or higher moment](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/108577/127719) could also be attracted to a charged balloon, but the force will be shorter range and much weaker.  For example, the net linear force on an electric quadrupole is proportional to the gradient of the gradient of the electric field. For a dipole and quadrupole made from identical charges with the same spacing $d$ in a spherically symmetric electric field, the force on a quadrupole is proportional to $d^2/r^4$, compared to $d/r^3$ for a dipole in the same field.

Molecules with quadrupole moments but no dipole moment include benzene (a carcinogen), ethylene glycol (a common antifreeze), and dioxane (an industrial solvent). As noted by @Puk in the comments, the quadrupole forces on a stream of dioxane are so weak as to be unobservable in a [simple experiment](https://youtu.be/5Hyy1zRZPiQ?t=1337). This is unsurprising. Since $d$ is the order of angstroms and $r$ is the order of centimetres, we expect the force on a fluid with only quadrupole molecular moments to be about a hundred million times weaker than the force on fluid with molecular dipole moments.

Comment: A quadrupole moment doesn't appear to cause significant attraction, at least not an effect that can easily be seen in a simple home setup. [Here is an illustration with dioxane.](https://youtu.be/5Hyy1zRZPiQ?si=A6Jt4-PECUyzABsw&t=1337)

Comment: Thanks @Puk. I've updated my answer to include the link you suggest and also a quantitative estimate of the relative weakness of dipole and quadruple forces.

Comment: @DavidBailey I would be willing to try a charged balloon with alcohol, but only under conditions that I designed.  In other words, a very thin stream of alcohol falling into a large bucket of water, with a fire extinguisher close by.